# Best farm route in Act 2

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to farm Act 2 Inferno but I think my farm route is not that fast enough. I can finish my run in about 40 mins.

My route:

1. Choose the Kill Zoltun Kulle quest
2. TP to Black Canyon Mines - at least 2 elites and/goblin
3. TP to Road to Alacarnus - at least 1 elite near the caged prisoners
4. TP to Zoltun Kulle base - there are 3 maps there but I skip the middle one because there are few elites there.
5. Kill Zoltun Kulle
6. End

The maps Storm Halls and Undead Halls (not sure about the name) are very big but I only encounter 3 - 4 elites there. I want to look for maps that have a high density of elites (with respect to the size of the map)

I tried the 2 caves in Desolate Sands but Desolate Sands is very big and I think I'm just wasting time exploring the map and looking for the caves.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than trying to do lots of fast runs, it is better to hunt out as many Packs as possible once you have a 5 stack.  Also, if you kill ZK, you can get to Belial in about 2 minutes, so if you are geared well enough you might as well kill him too in my opinion.

Comment: Where do you usually hunt elite packs? I just want to know what maps have the highest density of elites (other than Vault of the Assasin in Desolate Sands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely add the Ancient Path waypoint to that list, as there's often a goblin nearby.

I'd also recommend adding Vault of the Assassin to that list. Although it can take a while to find, you'll bump into a few elites while trying to find it, and once you do, the vault guarantees you a good number of elites once you get there.

I agree that Kulle's lair just doesn't seem to have enough elites to make it worthwhile.

I spent some time doing an "ActII lite" run, where I'd get checkpointed in the VoA, clear it, then hit the Black Canyon Mines, Ancient Path and Road to Alacarnus waypoints and end it there, without bothering with Kulle at all. The time saved by starting inside the Voa each time make the run feel a lot more efficient. It might have been entirely subjective, of course :)

Comment: I tried this last night and yes its effective. Vault of the Assasins is full of elites.